# How can i ad manual Text for treeView1 SelectedNode Text property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I tried this:

```
TreeView s = new TreeView();
s.SelectedNode.Text = "thisisfortesting1";
RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(s.SelectedNode, treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
```

I need that s.SelectedNode Text will be thisisfortesting1
But i'm getting exception null on the s.SelectedNode.Text = "thisisfortesting1"; on the SelectedNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `SelectedNode` is never set, i.e its null

This following is purely for academic purposes, however it shows you that if you have a `SelectedNode` set (either pragmatically or by the control), then you can proceed to set its text via the `SelectedNode.Text` property

```
TreeView s = new TreeView();
// create a new node
var node = new TreeNode();
// add it to the treeview
s.Nodes.Add(node);
// set the selected node
s.SelectedNode = node;
// set the selected node text
s.SelectedNode.Text = "thisisfortesting1";
```